# Imprimir caracteres especiais em c que estão em um arquivo.txt com biblioteca locale.h

Tags: c, arquivo, biblioteca, caracteres, locale

Meu programa de final de semestre da faculdade tem várias telas que imprimem textos grandes de `arquivo.txt`, porém, como faço em **linguagem C**, alguns caracteres não aparecem, como o `ç, é, ã...`E assim por diante.

Descobri uma biblioteca chamada `locale.h`. Com ela você pode escrever uns comandos que **fazem com que seu programa busque a linguagem do seu Sistema Operacional e com isso imprima os caracteres especiais**. 
No **ubuntu**, por exemplo...**A localidade brasileira é dada por:** “`pt_BR_utf8`″.

Segue um código ilustrativo do meu problema:

```
//Caracteres Especiais - Padrão PT/BR

`#include <locale.h>` 

//Biblioteca para definição de configuração local, necessario para o setlocale

    int main () 
    {
       printf("\nLocalidade Corrente: %s", setlocale(LC_ALL,NULL));
       printf("\nA localidade corrente agora  %s", setlocale(LC_ALL,""));
       //Com esse segundo printf, quer dizer que agora o programa está
       //habilitado a imprimir os caracteres especiais, certo?
       //Porém, eu imprimo o texto na função telaAjuda1() abaixo


       return(0);

    }

    void telaAjuda() {

    //Se o usuario digitar 1 aqui, o switch case vai chamar a função abaixo telaAjuda1(); - Numerei as funções, porque são 88. Achei mais fácil
    //de identificar mais tarde.

    }

    void telaAjuda1 ()
    {


        FILE *arq;
        char Linha[100];
        char *result;
        int i;
        system("clear");
        // Abre um arquivo TEXTO para LEITURA
        arq = fopen("telaAjuda1.txt", "rt");
        if (arq == NULL)  // Se houve erro na abertura
        {
            printf("Problemas na abertura do arquivo\n");
            return;
        }
        i = 1;
        while (!feof(arq))
        {
            // Lê uma linha (inclusive com o '\n')
            result = fgets(Linha, 100, arq);  // o 'fgets' lê até 99 caracteres ou até o '\n'
            if (result)  // Se foi possível ler
    //É no printf abaixo que imprimo o texto
                printf("\t%s",Linha);

            i++;
        }
        fclose(arq);

    }
```

OBS: Pensei que talvez poderia ser erro no meu terminal do ubuntu que não estava configurado para ler arquivos UTF-8, mas fui em configurações e ele está ok.

OBS 2: Abaixo um trecho do texto que não está imprimindo corretamente.

"O curso de Estruturas de Dados discute diversas técnicas de
programação, apresentando as estruturas de dados básicas 
utilizadas no desenvolvimento de software.

O conhecimento de linguagens de programação por si só não 
capacita programadores  é necessário saber usá-las de 
maneira eficiente. O projeto de um programa engloba a fase 
de identificação das propriedades dos dados e 
características funcionais". - W. Celes e J. L. Rangel

O problema: Mesmo eu olhando no terminal do ubuntu, e mesmo eu colocando o locale.h e configurando eu não estou entendendo o porque ele não está imprimindo corretamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você observou se o arquivo está em `utf-8`? Criei um arquivo aqui com seu texto e sem precisar incluir a biblioteca `locale.h` funcionou perfeitamente. Segue abaixo o meu teste.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    char string[300];
    fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
    while(1){
        fgets(string,300,fp);
        if(feof(fp)) break;
        puts(string);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

E o resultado obtido:
[image: Resultado]

Comment: Obrigada, o problema era esse mesmo. Tive que salvar em utf-8.